# Qt Debugger not Working Windows8

Tags: windows, qt

I have Qt5.5.1 with MSVC 2013 Compiler installed on Windows 8 PC, everything was working fine, but right now  while I am trying to debug the application I am getting the error like, `The CDB process terminated`, What could be the issue, I have attached the screen shot.

[image: Message while debugging]

[image: Kits settings]

[image: Debugger settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is because you are using the amd64 compiler with the x86 debugger; try setting both to the same (either amd64, or x86, but not mixed).

I had the same issue and this solved it for me...

Comment: The problem goes away when I remove all the Qt dll from debug directory and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and got it working by adding the required dlls to the "debug" build directory. To know which dlls are required, double-click on the .exe and it should tell you.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding ICU bin folder location to PATH, in my case **PATH=D:\Qt\5.4.1/3rdparty/icu/bin;%PATH%**